# Finding a Lower Bound on a Probability Expression

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Given $a<0<b$ and $X$ is a continuous random variable s.t. $\mathbb{P}(X < a) = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$, what upper and lower bounds can we find for $\mathbb{P}(X<b)$?

I find a lower bound by saying
$$ \mathbb{P}(X<b) + \mathbb{P}(X\ge b) = 1 $$
$$ \implies 1 - \mathbb{P}(X<b) = \mathbb{P}(X\ge b) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{b}=0 $$
$$ \implies \mathbb{P}(X<b)=1 $$
using [Markov's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) in the middle.

Is this correct? Is $1$ the lower and upper bound?

**Edit:** fixed a mistake in an assumption with Markov's inequality

Comment: You have a lower bound, not an upper bound, on $\mathbb{P}(X<b)$ by bounding $\mathbb{P}(X>b)\leq\dots$.

Comment: @user10354138 there was a typo there on the middle inequality. I fixed it.

Comment: You can't apply Markov inequality here for an upper bound of $\mathbb{P}(X<b)$, it only bounds the tail $\mathbb{P}(X>b)$.  Indeed, it is easy to cook up example to get $\mathbb{P}(X<b)=1$ here.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks, I fixed the mistakes in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bound is wrong since Markov's inequality assumes that $\mathbb{P}(X<0)=0.$ See the proof in Wikipedia for example. This is also why the $\mathbb{P}(X<a)=0$ never entered the picture.

Apply Markov to $Y=X+a,$ which obeys the assumption $\mathbb{P}(Y<0)=0$. This will give
$$
1-\mathbb{P}(Y<b) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(Y)}{b}=\frac{a}{b},
$$
leading to the lower bound
$$
1+ \frac{a}{b} \leq \mathbb{P}(Y<b) ,
$$
which is in $(0,1)$ since $b<0.$ Rewritten this gives
$$
1+ \frac{a}{b} \leq \mathbb{P}(X<b-a).
$$